# how to extract json path and find array length?

Tags: java, arrays, json, jmeter

how to extract JSON path and find array length using java? for my below response data. I need to validate array length should be equal to '7' in Jmeter assertion.

```
[
  [
    "Week",
    "Event Count"
  ],
  [
    "3/13/17",
    "1"
  ],
  [
    "3/20/17",
    "1"
  ],
  [
    "3/27/17",
    "1"
  ],
  [
    "4/3/17",
    "1"
  ],
  [
    "4/10/17",
    "1"
  ],
  [
    "4/17/17",
    "1"
  ]
]
```

Comment: Could you share your JSON data instead of response?

Comment: @fiskra, this my response data only

Answer (score 7):

1. Add [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) as a child of the request which produces the above JSON response and configure it as follows:

   - Variable names: anything meaningful, i.e. `week`
   - JSON Path Expressions: `$[*]`
   - Match No: `-1`

     [image: JMeter JSON Extractor]

   This will produce the following JMeter Variables (you can validate them using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler)):

   ```
   week_1=["Week","Event Count"]
   week_2=["3\/13\/17","1"]
   week_3=["3\/20\/17","1"]
   week_4=["3\/27\/17","1"]
   week_5=["4\/3\/17","1"]
   week_6=["4\/10\/17","1"]
   week_7=["4\/17\/17","1"]
   week_matchNr=7
   ```

   You are particularly interested in the latter one

   [image: JMeter Debug Sampler]
2. Add [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) as a child of the same request and configure it as follows:

   - Apply to: JMeter Variable -> `week_matchNr`
   - Pattern Matching Rules: `Equals`
   - Patterns to Test: `7`

   [image: JMeter Response Assertion Against JSON Variable]

   This way your sampler will pass if number of matches will be equal to 7 and otherwise it will fail. See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article to learn more about using assertions in JMeter tests.

Comment: cool stuffs, thanks @dmitri T but i'm using 2.13 version of J-meter. so i don't have JSON Exactor .

Comment: You can use [JSON Path Extractor](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) project. You can install JSON Path Extractor (as well as [JSON Path Assertion](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathAssertion/)) using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

Comment: Every way I look at their specs, $[*].length() should work, but it just doesn’t. Seems like a bug in JSONPath or jmeter to me. Good work-around.

Comment: I implement greater operator with JSR223 Assertion (groovy): `return vars.get("week_matchNr").toInteger() > 0;`